# Lookupvalue that is equal or between two values

Tags: java, collections

I have a CSV file that links a region to a zip code. It looks like this (lowest-zip, highest-zip, region):

```
1600,1799,1
1800,1899,1
4300,4699,1
2820,2839,2
2850,2879,2
2930,2949,2
5600,5819,3
5850,6514,3
6516,6549,3
6800,6849,3
```

I need a function that returns the region based on the zip code. Something like this:

```
foo = getRegion(1600) // foo is set to 1
bar = getRegion(1642) // bar is set to 1
baz = getRegion(4351) // baz is set to 2
qux = getRegion(1211) // qux is set to null
```

The way I currently implemented this is using a `HashMap`. When I read the  CSV I iterate over every value between 1600 and 1799 and create a key-value pair for each zip code / region combination and repeat that for every row in the CSV. The result is a `HashMap` looking like this:

```
1600,1
1601,1
1602,1
...
1799,1
1800,2
1801,2
...
```

This creates a large `HashMap`, which does work. Is there a more (memory) efficient implementation than exploding this small table to a large `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like below will help -

```
class ZipRange {
    int start;
    int end;
}

// Fill up this map parsing through csv
Map<ZipRange, Integer> zipToRegion;

int zipToSearch = 2870;

// Create method which returns integer which corresponds to region
for (ZipRange zip : zipToRegion.keySet()) {
    if (zipToSearch >= zip.start && zipToSearch <= zip.end) {
        return zipToRegion.get(zip);
    }
}
return -1;
```

Comment: I think you want to implement `hashCode` and `equals` for your `ZipRange` class :-)

Comment: yes sure. this was to give basic idea on data structure to use and algo to search.

Comment: if the input intervals are not overlapping, you may "abuse" `hashCode` and `equals` such that `ZipRange(1600, 1799)` and `ZipRange(1642, 1642)` are the same ... then you don't need to loop over the `keySet`

Comment: based upon OP's requirement, it it quite improbable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: I thought of that. I created a sklearn.tree in python to see how it looked. There is not much logic in the relation between zips and reg ions, it results in a complex tree and I cannot change the way the data is delivered to me.

Comment: @MartijnBurger: I don't mean a "Decision Tree" like those provided by `sklearn.tree`, but a "Segment Tree" or "Interval Tree": [see for example here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/interval-tree/)

Comment: Thanks. Looks interesting. I'll look into that.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12082020)

Comment: @GHajba: you're right, however, I think the Web is about "linking to information" rather than "replicating it" :) ... also, I don't always have the time to write a lot :)